How to add @react-native-community/eslint-config to eslint.config.mjs
I have learnt that in the eslintrc.js, the react-native-community/eslint-config is added to it in the following way. However, I am now using ESLINT v9 which use eslint.config.mjs. How do i add it to eslint.config.mjs now?
eslintrc.js way
module.exports = {
root: true,
parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
plugins: [
'@typescript-eslint',
],
extends: [
'@react-native-community',
'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
],
};
how to add react-native-community/eslint-config to eslint.config.mjs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
